# How can I reformat XAML nicely in VS 2008?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, formatting

Visual Studio 2008's XAML editor (SP1) cannot reformat the XML into a consistent style.

Which tools can I use to get a nicely formatted XAML file? Studio integration preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link that is specific to VS2008 XAML formatting but the good news is you can do it directly inside VS.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116172353/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/09/29/cleaning-up-xaml-code-and-improving-parsing-time-with-blend.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

While browsing through the options, I found that I had to set "Position each attribute on a separate line" and "Position first attribute on same line as start tag" under "Tools > Options ... > Text-Editor > XAML > Formatting > Spacing" and reset the Keyboard mappings under "Tools > Options ... > Environment > Keyboard" to "Visual C# 2005".

Now the XAML editor reformats the XAML to my taste when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: My blog post about these settings - http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2009/02/19/auto-formatting-the-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd>?!

Comment: VS 2008's XAML Editor doesn't recognize that as a chord.

Comment: VS2010 done - it's actually CTRL-K,CTRL-D  (Edit.FormatDocument is what it equates to)
And works quite nicely at first glance

Answer (score 2):

Karl just released v2 of his XAML Power toys and it can reformat your xaml from VS2008! Check out the video about XAML Power Toys Accessories

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/xaml-power-toys-v2-release-finally-code-name-hawaii/

Answer (score 2):

Or try xaml styler hosted at http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/ for visual studio 2010.
If you ever used Kaxaml's Xaml Scrubber and you like it, then you could think of this extension is the "Xaml Scrubber" for Visual Studio.

Check http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/ for feature highlights.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I found is [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), which does nice formatting ("XAML Scrubber" entry in the left menu), but being a stand-alone editor doesn't quite make the cut.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dimebrain.com/2008/05/automating-read.html is a nice plugin for formatting your xaml so the attributes line up underneath each other.

Comment: That just does what the VS2008 editor can do himself, if the options are set right.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a post on this. This is a very versatile way to format XAML.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/01/09/how-to-format-xaml-easily-and-effectively-windows-8-wpf-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but as said in my own answer, being a stand-alone editor doesn't quite make the cut, because it doesn't fit into a programming workflow.